# add class and remove class from selected button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger the selected `link` there are 4 attributes `href` which performs onclick function. I want to add class active to the one which is selected can anyone help me out with this concern

```
<ul class="graph_menu">
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>, '-1 month', 'Pkr');">1 M</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>, '-3 months', 'Pkr');">3 M</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>, '-6 months', 'Pkr');">6 M</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>, '-1 year', 'Pkr');">1 Y</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>, '-3 years', 'Pkr');">3 Y</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>, 'all', 'Pkr');">Max</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the function I have created

```
function getCompanyRatesGraph(val, timeFrame, gd_type) {
    $(this).removeClass('.active');
    $(this).addClass('.active');
    $('.load_dt_grph').show();
}
```

Comment: `$(".grph_btn").removeClass("active")`,  and you dont need the `.` in `('.active')`, should be `('active')`

Comment: it's adding active class to all href with having class name of the same

Comment: Usman what do you mean?

Comment: You need to do `$(this).removeClass('active');` and `$(this).addClass('active');`.
If you will use `$(".grph_btn").addClass("active")` then if will add `active` class to every `href`. Use `$(this)` for just selected ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$(".grph_btn").removeClass("active");` to remove active from all the buttons.

Also remove the dot from `('.active')`

Also you need to add `this` to your onclick event. because your function dont know what `this` is

```js
function getCompanyRatesGraph(val, timeFrame, gd_type, obj) {
  $(".grph_btn").removeClass("active");
  $(obj).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="graph_menu">
  <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph('', '-1 month', 'Pkr', this);">1 M</a></li>
  <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph('', '-3 months', 'Pkr', this);">3 M</a></li>
  <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph('', '-6 months', 'Pkr', this);">6 M</a></li>
  <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph('', '-1 year', 'Pkr', this);">1 Y</a></li>
  <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph('', '-3 years', 'Pkr', this);">3 Y</a></li>
  <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph('', 'all', 'Pkr', this);">Max</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: run my code and check again, make sure you wrote everything correct

Comment: @UsmanKhan Also notice, that you have to added `'Pkr', this` to your onclick event. and in your function has to be `getCompanyRatesGraph(val, timeFrame, gd_type, obj)`. Then `$(obj).addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getCompanyRatesGraph(ele, val, timeFrame, gd_type) {
    $('.grph_btn').removeClass('active');
    $(ele).addClass('active');
    $('.load_dt_grph').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="graph_menu">
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(this, 1, '-1 month', 'Pkr');">1 M</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(this, 2, '-3 months', 'Pkr');">3 M</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(this, 3, '-6 months', 'Pkr');">6 M</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(this, 4, '-1 year', 'Pkr');">1 Y</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(this, 5, '-3 years', 'Pkr');">3 Y</a></li>
    <li><a class="grph_btn" onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(this, 6, 'all', 'Pkr');">Max</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @UsmanKhan You can see that both hassan and my answer works fine when you run the snippet, please make sure that you wrote your html correctly according to our answer and if so, tell us what is not working. You can also include your "new" html and jquery code

Comment: yeah sorry now i checked via inspect element

Comment: Both of the answer are virtually the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use toggleclass :-

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla solution:

`this.classList.add('active')`

`this.classList.remove('active')`

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick to remove any active class is to search for that class and remove it from itself. So instead of

```
$('.grph_btn').removeClass('active');
```

You can use

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Then on to the function

```
$('.grph_btn').onClick(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```